# Math Question! Can u solve it?

Tags: mathematics

This took me 25 seconds! How long did it take you?

11 X 11 = 4

22 X 22 = 16

33 X 33 = ???

The answer is right in front of you so do not think in normal math rules!

Comment: You have 3 question marks. Does that mean we are looking for a 3-digit answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three question marks, so the following should be a better fit:

> $(1!+1!)\times(1!+1!)=4$
>  $(2!+2!)\times(2!+2!)=16$
>  $(3!+3!)\times(3!+3!)=144$

Comment: That is correct @WhatsUp! You got the correct answer!

Answer (score 5):

> $(1+1)\times(1+1)=4$
>  $(2+2)\times(2+2)=16$
>  $(3+3)\times(3+3)=36$

Answer (score 1):

Same answer, different logic:

> the numbers represent how many $5\times5$ squares can be cut from the given rectangle, e.g.
>  $11\times11$ – 4 squares,
>  $22\times22$ – 16 squares,
>  $33\times33$ – 36 squares.